# email verification with button in the email content php

Tags: php, email

I have email verification. Instead of link I want a button that a user can click. here is my code:

```
$confirmMailContent = "Thank you for registering. Please click <a href='[LINK]'>here</a> to confirm your email address";
```

It works, but instead of a clickable link I want a button. Any ideas? I tried

```
$confirmMailContent = "Thank you for registering. Please click <a href=<button type='button' name='btn-signup'></button>here</a> to confirm your email address";
```

It didn't work.

Comment: Style your link as a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use css in the way you wish to style the link as button, **here's an example:**

```css
.link-button {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4;
}

.link-button:hover, .link-button:focus, .link-button:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #204d74;
  border-color: #122b40;
}
```

```html
Thank you for registering. Please click 
      <a href='[LINK]' class="link-button">here</a>
to confirm your email address
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not add css?

```
$confirmMailContent = "Thank you for registering. Please click <a href='#link' style='background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;'>here</a> to confirm your email address";
```

this is a simple example

Answer (score 1):

```
$confirmMailContent = "Thank you for registering. Please click <a href='your-link'><button type='button' name='btn-signup'></button></a> to confirm your email address";
```

You need to close the **a tag**

Comment: yes. that what it was. I forgot the < before button.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the < before the button.
Thank you everyone who tried to help.